# How to use external data with CACTI

Tags: cacti

I am using some perl and bash scripts to create rrd files for some other application. My simple query is, can I use cacti to make graphs using that rrd files.

Note: I am able to create graphs using rrd tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go throuth the manual of [CACTI](http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I found a guide on cacti manual on http://docs.cacti.net/manual:087:8_rrdtool.05_external_rrds

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can do something like this:

1. Create "Data Input Methods" and create some "Input Fields" as you requirement, because you have .pl or .sh scripts
2. Create Data Templates and other Templates
3. Add devices and create graphs relation to the devices